# How to properly render child routes in Vue.js using $router.push

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a Vue component called `Layout` which contains two named views:

```html
<template>
  <router-view name="navigation"></router-view>
  <router-view name="content"></router-view>
</template>
```

This is my router definition:

```js
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: Layout,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'Login',
          components: {
            navigation: Navigation,
            content: Login
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      component: Layout,
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'Dashboard',
          components: {
            navigation: Navigation,
            content: Dashboard
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

My `Navigation` component has a specific logic that shows a different navigation bar depending on whether the user is logged-in or not and works perfectly.

In my `Login` component I have an event handler that does the following:

```js
this.$router.push({name: 'Dashboard'})
```

This line causes the `Dashboard` view to replace the `Login` view in the `content` named view but the `navigation` named view does not change and stays the same. The expected behavior is for it to be re-rendered and display different elements based on the new data.

The expected behavior does happen if I do a full page reload but not when a `$router.push()` call is performed. I can't get to find what is that I'm doing wrong. How can I achieve the intended behavior?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html), this happens because once rendered, components are re-used and not parsed again. The `Navigation` component is always rendered, so it's only parsed on its first appearance. The solution for this is to watch the `$route` object, adding this code to the Navigation component causes it to be parsed appropriately:

```js
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    if (from.name === 'Login' || from.name === 'Logout') {
      this.generateNavigationLinks()
    }
  }
}
```